# Getting Problem in Layout Upon Using Lottie Animation in Gatsby and Material UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

**Getting Problem in Layout Upon Using Lottie Animation in Gatsby and Material UI. Heres the code**

```
import React from "react"
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid"
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography"
import Lottie from "react-lottie"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import useMediaQuery from "@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery"

import data from "../../images/data.json"

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  textContainer: {
    padding: "2rem",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
      padding: "1rem",
    },
  },
  heading: {
    [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
      fontSize: "3.5rem",
    },
  },
}))

export default function HeroBlock() {
  const animationData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
  const classes = useStyles()

  const matchesLG = useMediaQuery(theme => theme.breakpoints.down("lg"))
  const matchesMD = useMediaQuery(theme => theme.breakpoints.down("md"))
  const matchesXS = useMediaQuery(theme => theme.breakpoints.down("xs"))

  const defaultOptions = {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: false,
    animationData,
  }

  return (
    <Grid container justifyContent="space-around" alignItems="center">
      <Grid item classes={{ root: classes.textContainer }}>
        <Grid container direction="column">
          <Grid item>
            <Typography
              align="center"
              variant="h1"
              classes={{ root: classes.heading }}
            >
              The Premier
              <br />
              Developer Clothing Line
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography align="center" variant="h3">
              high quality, custom-designed shirts, hats, and hoodies
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Lottie
          isStopped
          options={defaultOptions}
          width={
            matchesXS
              ? "20rem"
              : matchesMD
              ? "30rem"
              : matchesLG
              ? "40rem"
              : "50rem"
          }
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

Here is the SS of My Layout. The Animation Should be in column but it is stacked up.
[Here is the SS of my Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eaj8b.png)

And when i inspect in the console the Lottie animation generating new div with styles and in that div the lottie animation reside. Here is the div which i have inspected in console

```
<div style="width: 40rem; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px auto; outline: currentcolor none medium;">
Inside the div the Lottie animation is running. 
</div>
```

So i think the main prbolem is with this div. How to solve this problem.

Comment: Why are you using all `Grid` components? You can use `Box` with flex. The very first component should be `<Box display="flex" flexDirection="column">` rather than `<Grid container ...>` based on the design.

Comment: I am new to Material UI. thats why i am exploring all of the library and its components.

Comment: The main Problem is that div. Not Grid

Comment: What if you would remove the `Lottie` component?

Comment: When i remove the lottie component then layout works fine as expected and that div also disappeared.

Comment: I think it was a width issue. I have set the lottie component's width inline and now it works as expected but its still a mystery that how that div is generating even i don't have such code in my files.

Comment: you can style the Lottie component `width: 100%`.